# html table - which column will give?

Tags: html, html-table

When you have a table where you define explicitly the width per `<td>` and the total is greater than the existing width that you have to play with.  what determines which column will shrink and which will enforce the td width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Two table rendering algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#h-B.5.2) are recommended in Appendix B of the HTML 4.01 specification.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you can apply width in percentage and keep one of the columns as auto width(dont apply any width to it).

Answer (score -1):

The browser rendering it makes the choice, plus other factors such as how you have set the widths.

Why not set one column to be auto width? then this one will be the one to size, or use percentages?